# Can I use WCF in this case?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

We have a third party application that provied its web services to us by ASMX and it is created at the time of .NET 1.1
in the old days we were using VB 6.0 and connected to it by a PocketSOAP, etc...
bt now we want to replace the VB 6.0 with C# 3.5 WinApps  and still use that third party web services.
so I wish to know what are my options for doing this? which one do you recommend and which one has a faster learning curve?

Thanks All.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to use consume the old web service only and want to replace your client application which was done using VB6.0. You dont have to use WCF here, you can create your client application using Win Forms/WPF. WCF is for providing service and in your case you want a client application.

My opinion will be to use WPF or .net winforms.

Comment: yes exactly : " want to use consume the old web service only and want to replace your client application which was done using VB6.0."
... so How my new Clinet (WinForms) is going to connect to that existing service?  using WCF? using older WebService technologies in .NET ?  which technology you recommend for this purpose?

Comment: You can directly consume the old Webservice using winforms, dont have to use WCF. Just create new winform application and right click on the project in solution explorer, select Add Web Reference and provide the old web service url.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "which one", what is the other option you're referring to?
But yes, you can use WCF as a client to an .asmx web service.

Just add a service reference like you would to a WCF service. It will use the WSDL to generate a client proxy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) in WCF to interoperate with legacy services.